# Prove that $L(l, Y) $ and $l_y^\infty $are isometrically isomorphic spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $(Y, ||   ||)$ be a Banach space and $ l_y^\infty$ space of all bounded sequences by norm $ (y_n)\to sup\{ ||y_n|| : n∈N\}$.
Prove that $L(l, Y) $ and $l_y^\infty $ are isometrically isomorphic spaces.

( where $L(l, Y)$ is space of all bounded linear operators $l\to Y$, and $l$ is space of all sequences in $Y$)

I don’t know how to constuct the isometric isomorphism.

Comment: This is obviously false. Did the problem actually ask this or was it "prove or disprove"?

Comment: The problem was to prove this.

Comment: Think about the case where $Y$ has finite dimension...